# Find parent of an element in HTML DOM tree

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to find the parent of the span element with label **First Name** and go up the DOM until i get to the **input** element with class "*mat-input-element*" 
I have attempted with the following xpath, but did not get the result i needed:

```
   //div/div/span[contains(.,'First Name')]/parent::div[@class='add-users']/lib-text-input-v3/div/mat-form-field/div/div/div[1]/input
```

[image: HTML DOM]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with the below xpath.

```
//span[normalize-space(.)='First Name']/ancestor::div[@class='input-v3']//input[@class='mat-input-element']
```

Sample HTML: From jsfiddle

```html
<html><head></head><body>
    <div class="add-users">
    <lib-text-input-v3 errortext="”Error" a="" valid="" first="" name”="">
        <div class="input-v3">
       <mat-form-field class="mat-form-field">
          <div class="mat-form-field-wrapper">
             <div class="mat-form-field-flex">
                <div class="mat-form-field-infix">
            <input class="mat-input-element" type="text">
                   <span class="mat-form-field-label-wrapper">
                   </span>
                </div>
             </div>
             <div class="mat-form-field-underline>
                <span class=" mat-form-field-ripple"="">
                
             </div>
             <div class="mat-form-field-subscript-wrapper">
                <div class="mat-form-field-hint-wrapper">
                   <div class="mat-form-field-hint-spacer">
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>. //closes mat-form-field-wrapper class
       </mat-form-field>
    <div class="input-v3__label"> // same level as input-v3 class
       <div class="input-v3__label--text">
          <span class="ng-tns-c11-01">First Name
          </span>&nbsp; 
       </div>
   </div>
  </div> // closes input-v3 class
</lib-text-input-v3>
<lib-text-input-v3>…..
</lib-text-input-v3></div></body></html>
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the html DOM rather screenshot, if the xpath didn't work.

Comment: It didn't work. You had a typo with two forward slashes before input, but even after removing it, no luck.

Comment: can you please share the html dom, rather the screenshot. Two `//` means any child nodes.

Comment: I see the `"` is not closed property for the `input` element `class attribute value`. When I fixed that as shown in the sample code in the updated answer, the xpath is working as expected with the updated xpath and html.

Comment: Please check and let me know if you are still facing issue.

Comment: +1 for the effort, it still doesn't work for me. Bad selectors like "//lib-text-input-v3/div/mat-form-field/div/div/div/input" do work, but that's not how i want to use it.

Comment: @supputuri's answer is just fine. Something shorter : `//span[contains(.,'First Name')]/preceding::input[@class="mat-input-element"]`

Comment: @E.Wiest actually both do work if i remove the class on the input. Not sure why that is not accepted.

Comment: have you tried with the html that I shared? The class name  was incorrect in code that you shared in jsfiddle. Check the difference between my html and your jsfillde at`input` tag.